# Calling wp_mail() twice in same function (the second one will not be sent)

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm calling wp_mail() function twice in same function but the other one (second one) is not sending. Am I missing something?

```
function v_send_mail() {
    wp_mail( "firstemail@gmail.com", $subject, $msg, $headers );
    wp_mail( "secondemail@gmail.com", $subject, $msg, $headers );
}

echo v_send_mail();
```

If I reverse their positioning, the first email will not receive the email. Any solutions?

Comment: A function doesn't return multiple multiple things, so it will return only one email function, why cant you use two functions for two wp_email()?

Comment: @charankumar Oh I see. It's an auto responder which will be sent to the client email and to our emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
function v_send_mail() {
    $group_emails = array("firstemail@gmail.com", "secondemail@gmail.com" );
    wp_mail($group_emails, 'my subject', 'my message', $headers);
}

if(v_send_mail()){
    echo "mail sent";
}
```

Comment: Wow @Vel, didn't know that WPMail can handle multiple recipient. I shoul've know that sooner. Thankyou :D